# Datatable : dtInstance.columns.adjust() is not working properly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, datatable, angular-datatables

I want to create an responsive table using angular datatable. I used `dtInstance.columns.adjust()` to adjust column depend on the screen width.

It is not working if I used First Code,

First Code:

```
this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: any) => {
 dtInstance.clear().destroy();
 dtInstance.columns.adjust();
})
```

but it is working if I used `settimeout` (second Code) only in laptop or PCs not mobile.

Second code:

```
this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: any) => {
 dtInstance.clear().destroy();
 setTimeout(function(){ 
  dtInstance.columns.adjust();
 }, 1000);
});
```

Can anyone suggest a proper way to adjust the columns?